# How do I get python to recognise an RGB input?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-3.6

My goal is to allow the user to input RGB values for both variables, but I do not know how to get Python to recognise an RGB value with a tag beforehand, such as with the `int` and `float` tags. An example of my code is shown below.

```
shape_fill = input ("Which color do you want to fill your shape? Please enter an RGB value.  ") )
shape_pen = input ("Which color do you want the outline of your shape to be? Please enter an RGB value.  ")
```

Does anyone have the solution?

BTW - I am using Turtle Graphics, does this have any effect?

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I have now solved this problem. I achieved this by splitting the RGB value into three different `int`s and asking the user to `input` three different values.

Answer (score 0):

Just let the user input comma-separated values:

```
R, G, B = map(float, input("Enter comma-separated: ").split(','))
```

So, when one enters `2.3, 6.7, 34.8`, the values of `R`, `G` and `B` will be floats extracted from the input.

You can also do:

```
shape_fill = map(...)
shape_pen = map(...)
```

And then *unpack* the floats later on with `R, G, B = shape_something`.

Comment: Sorry @ForceBru, but that doesn't seem to work. The Error Message says that the `string ` couldn't be converted to a `float`.

Comment: @A.Kassam, oh, I'm sorry, I forgot to add an important argument to `split`. Should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

The following might do what you want -- an issue that hasn't been mentioned in the previous discussion is `turtle.colormode()` which affects whether you want int or float input:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def input_rgb(prompt=""):
    triple = None

    text = prompt + "Enter comma-separated RGB values: "

    while True:
        try:
            triple_string = input(text).split(',', maxsplit=2)

            if len(triple_string) != 3:
                continue

            if isinstance(screen.colormode(), float):
                triple = map(float, triple_string)
            else:
                triple = map(int, triple_string)

        except ValueError:
            continue

        break

    return triple

screen = Screen()

yertle = Turtle(shape="turtle")

yertle.fillcolor(input_rgb("Fill color? "))
yertle.pencolor(input_rgb("Outline color? "))

yertle.begin_fill()
yertle.circle(100)
yertle.end_fill()

screen.exitonclick()
```

USAGE

```
% python3 test.py
Fill color? Enter comma-separated RGB values: 1.0,0.0,0.0
Outline color? Enter comma-separated RGB values: 0.0,0.0,1.0
```

OUTPUT

[image]

The next challenge (for you) is to convert `input_rgb()` to use the turtle graphic input routines instead of `input()`:

```
turtle.textinput(title, prompt)
turtle.numinput(title, prompt, default=None, minval=None, maxval=None)
```

Comment: Sorry, @cdlane, but my code comes up with the following error message:

Comment: NameError: name 'screen' is not defined

Comment: @A.Kassam I just copied my answer from the SO page into a file and it runs fine under Python 3.6.0.  You must have miscopied something, recheck and try again.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it does change the input methods if you use turtle graphics
Try looking [at this website](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/turtle.html) and see if that helps.